# Selecting multiple table columns and alias conditions in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, orm

I would like to achieve this query in laravel..

```
select sum(reading * multiplier) as consumption, reading_date, count(id) as num, (sum(reading * multiplier) / count(id)) as average 
from electricities where meter_name != '' ;
```

so far i have this

```
electricities = Electricity::select(DB::raw('sum(reading * multiplier) as consumption', 'reading_date', 'count(id) as num', '(sum(reading * multiplier) / count(id)) as average'))
                                        ->where('factory_code', '=', $request->$factory_code)
                                        ->whereYear('reading_date', $request->$year)
                                        ->groupBy(DB::raw('month(reading_date)'))
                                        ->orderBy('reading_date', 'asc')
                                        ->get();
```

but it would not return the desired output..

can anyone help me with this? thanks

Comment: remove `where`, `whereYear`, `groupBy`, `orderBy`, and add `where('meter_name', '<>', '')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your Query:

```
electricities = Electricity::select(DB::raw('sum(reading * multiplier) as consumption', 'reading_date', 'count(id) as num', '(sum(reading * multiplier) / count(id)) as average'))
                                        ->where('meter_name', '!=', '')
                                        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Electricity::where('id', '=', $user->id)->get(['product_name as name','product_price as price']);
```